# identifying and cloning the superblock of a raid0 mdadm v0.90 array

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid0

> /dev/sdb13      174706938   976768064   401030563+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

The size of that partition is **802061126** sectors. From what i read - mdadm should have placed the actual superblock somewhere inbetween **128K** and **64K** to the very end. This is a **raid0** array. The problem that i am facing is that i need to move the superblock on another partition/drive (sda13) which is currently shifted/spaced out (basically it shrunk and i need to expand it to the size of sdb13). I need to get the exact location/dimensions, a definite 1:1 (nothing extra or less). I have tried inspecting the partition in question with **dd** and **xxd** to inspect the start/end of the superblock - but it is somewhat misleading, i do not see any pattern of mdadm specific headers to be able to identify it. So far, i have only been able to locate the **UUID** (bytes are reversed: *7c6afc87* it stored as *87fc6a7c*) - but still cannot make out either the end or the start of mdadm headers.

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Check out its version exactly: `sudo mdadm -E /dev/sdb13`

Comment: `Version : 0.90.00` as i've already said

Comment: You didn't say that `mdadm -E` works fine and shows the info, actually.

Comment: take a look at the thread's name. blatantly says "0.90", does it not? also, what do you mean by "mdadm -E works fine and shows the info, actually" - i never said it did not, huh? btw, it only shows the superblock offsets for 1.2

Comment: `mdadm -E` also should indicate offset of data and superblock in sectors.

Comment: for 1.2, not 0.90